# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 'xx.domain.xx' port 8140 after 1167 ms: Connection refused

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl, connection-refused

URL error 7: Failed to connect to 'xx.domain.xx' port 8140 after 1167 ms: Connection refused

Hi guys, im trying to connect to a public api using curl but response is always at cURL error 7.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please share your code and if it is a public api the endpoint url too?

Comment: Bro how do you fixed this ?